# Create Folder in External Android Storage (nativescript)

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to create a folder "my" in external storage of android of an nativescript-angular application.

I get this error:

```
> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failed to create new java
> File for path /storage/emulated/0/Download/my"
```

I use this code to create the "my" Folder at "/storage/emulated/0/Download/my":

```
    const env = android.os.Environment;
    this.androidDownloadsPath = path.join(env.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        env.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
    );
    this.myFolderPath = path.join(this.androidDownloadsPath, 
    this.myFolder = Folder.fromPath(this.myFolderPath);
```

Read&Write permissions are in the android-manifest.xml file (default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android SDK API Level >23, it is necessary to additionally request the READ/WRITE Permissions. The user has to manually accept them (dialog). Use "nativescript-permissions" plugin to accomplish this.

Afterwards its possible to create a folder and files in `/sdcard`

```
 const directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
 const path1 = path.join(directory, "MyFolder");
 const folder = Folder.fromPath(path1);

 let file = folder.getFile(filename);
        file.writeText(JSON.stringify(content) || "some random content")
            .then(result => {
                file.readText()
                    .then(res => {
                        log("Successfully saved in " + file.path);
                        console.log("read file: " + file.readTextSync());
                    });

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```